# Disable Visual Studio automatically syncing commits (pulling)

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I am still pretty new to Git & repositories and currently hitting a wall with trying to configure Visual Studio Source Control.

My problem is that whenever someone pushes a commit to the master (or a branch), the commit gets automatically pulled and merged on every machine. Incoming is always at (0). I tried my best to search for a solution online but couldn't find anything that worked. In my old company, everything was set up so we could manually fetch and pull everything.

How can I do this in Visual Studio 2022?
(We are using Azure DevOps in Visual Studio for our projects.)

Comment: Wow, that seems like a very poor choice of configuration. I've never even heard of auto-sync that would pull and merge automatically like this. It would drive me insane!

Comment: I would ask your IT department. This seems so unusual, I am thinking it has to be the result of some corporate policy and something that's been deployed on your network. If so, they should know how it's deployed and how to configure it.

Comment: Maybe your IT department is (ab)using git to sync document folders (like with onedrive or similar tools). For this it would make sense, but certainly not for source code.

Comment: Are you sure it's VS that's doing the sync?

Comment: To summarize what happened here: **Question:** "Why is it automatically syncing?" **Answer:** "Oh... It's because I was manually pressing the Sync button." I love how genuine this is. Surely everyone has had moments like this in their lives at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much.
I talked to IT which I should have done in the first place.

The problem was user-input-related.
To be specific, I mixed up the "Refresh" and the "Sync" buttons in the new Visual Studio UI. Which (in my defense) do look very similar.
So I was hitting *Synchronize* instead of *Refresh* on the machines

Problem solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah, the gui could really just say `fetch` and `pull` instead... I prefer just using the command line for exactly this kind of reason